# In PHP, how to check if TCP port is available?

Tags: php, tcp, port

how do i check if a tcp port is available in PHP?

(i saw this question asked for a lot of other languages, but didn't find one for PHP)

Comment: It would be essentially the same in PHP as other languages. Try to bind the port with `socket_bind()`. If it's available this will succeed.

Comment: @Barmar that makes perfect sense, but i am surprised that it was hard to find a pre-made solution ^^ (i found it for Java and C# and Python and a bunch of other languages, but not PHP)

Answer (score 0):

not well tested, but i think it's something like

```php
function is_tcp_port_available(int $port, int &$error_code = null, string &$error_description = null):bool{
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP );
    if(!$sock){
        $error_code = socket_last_error();
        $error_description = socket_strerror($error_code);
        return false;
    }
    // use @ to be compatible with ErrorException
    if(!@socket_bind($sock, "0.0.0.0", $port)){
        $error_code = socket_last_error($sock);
        $error_description = socket_strerror($error_code);        
        socket_close($sock);
        return false;
    }
    $error_code = 0;
    $error_description = "";
    socket_close($sock);
    return true;
}
```